# How to disable autorun for all drives

Tags: powershell, windows-xp

I need to run a powershell script that disables autorun for ALL drives on a computer.

It can be done manually as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715), but I need to do it for multiple computers (with Windows XP and 7) using a WDS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
function Disable-AutoRun
{
    $item = Get-Item `
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\AutoRun.inf" `
        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $item) {
        $item = New-Item "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\AutoRun.inf"
    }
    Set-ItemProperty $item.PSPath "(default)" "@SYS:DoesNotExist"
}
```

and this to re-enable:

```
function Enable-AutoRun
{
    Remove-Item "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\AutoRun.inf" -Force
}
```

[Explication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/17/using-powershell-to-protect-against-conficker-enabling-and-disabling-autorun-inf.aspx).

Comment: For any drive that have autorun.inf in the root.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
$path ='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer'
Set-ItemProperty $path -Name NoDriveTypeAutorun -Type DWord -Value 0xFF
```